# gcloud app enigne. where to create virtualenv? external directory to my project?

Tags: python, gcloud, virtual-environment

I'm starting to use gcloud and appengine and I don't know which is the best way to manage virtualenvs.

On the one hand, https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/quickstart

> Create an isolated Python environment in a directory external to your project and activate it

But on the other hand, https://cloud.google.com/python/setup

```
cd your-project
python3 -m venv venv
```

So, what should I do? I understand that the logic of creating the virtualenv outside the directory is due to not deploying the virtualenv when deploying the gcloud app, but there is no way to exclude it? If I'm working with vs code, I think that the virtualenv should be in the same folder where is the project.

Thanks for the help, my first question in stackoverflow!

Answer (score 1):

Have you made sure that .venv and other folders such as .vscode are in .gcloudignore? Once I removed them from the file, my deployment started working.

Answer (score 0):

This might help.

gcloud app engine do not need a separate virtual environment.

please refer to the official document carefully.
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/quickstart

Visit this link you sent in your question.
https://cloud.google.com/python/setup

They've mentioned clearly that this is. 
**To run the Hello World app on your local computer:**

Write your dependencies in requirements.txt and keep it in root foler of your project, gcp app engine will internally manage all your dependencies(packages).

consider the hierarchy.

```
ProjectFolder
->AppFolder
->manage.py
->requirements.txt
```

let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you keep the venv distinct from the project's sources (i.e. anything you'd like manage through source control).

I generally favor:

```sh
mkdir -p ${PROJECT}/python ${PROJECT}/venv
tree -L 1 ${PROJECT}
${PROJECT}
├── python
└── venv
```

This keeps the project together but permits me to whack `${PROJECT}/venv` as I wish and it does not taint the code that gets deployed to e.g. App Engine.

I didn't see much of an inconsistency in the Google-published guidance.

You want to ensure that the venv directory is **not** deployed to App Engine.